# Programmatically create new order in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

We are using Woocommerce version `2.0.20.`

We are trying to create a new order Programmatically.

```php
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'myfunction');
    function myfunction() {
    $order = wc_create_order();
    $order->add_product( wc_get_product($productid), 1); // This is an existing SIMPLE product
    $order->set_address( $address, 'billing' );
    $order->calculate_totals();
    $order->update_status("Completed", 'Order status', TRUE); 
}
```

But when i call this code order is not created.

Answer (score 0):

`wc_get_product` was only introduced in 2.2.0. If you're using 2.0.2, try using `get_product` (deprecated in 3.0) instead.

The code snippet is also incomplete so it's difficult to diagnose. `$productid` and `$address` are empty in the snippet.

Comment: Hello, I am using like this $address = array('first_name' => 'TEst','last_name' =>'lst','email'=> 'tst@tst.com','phone'=> '4545454545','address_1'  => '123 Main st,San Diego,Ca'); $order->add_product( get_product(2143), 1);

Comment: You're running this on the `woocommerce_checkout_process ` action which get's fired when the checkout form is submitted. Are you submitting the checkout form? Maybe you need to change the action to `init`?

Comment: No i am not submitting the checkout form. I will change the action to init.

Comment: Hello, Is wc_create_order() working in Woocommerce version 2.0.20? Or i need to add other function?